# Getting Imap Details for microsoft exchange account using Autodiscover

Tags: python, exchangewebservices

Using '**Calling Autodiscover**' section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332364.aspx I could get Autodiscover xml response. I extracted 'EwsUrl' from xml response but how to get imap details for exchange account from that? I need imap details to fetch mails from that account .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get IMAP information from the SOAP Autodiscover endpoint, but I don't believe the POX endpoint returns it.

You would want to request the `InternalImap4Connections` and `ExternalImap4Connections` settings. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dd877068(v=exchg.150).aspx for documentation, and see https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-Get-user-7e22c86e for a .NET code sample you can use to experiment with.